# Resize a button less than 1 pixel like (0.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to resize my buttons height & weight less than 1. Is that possible?
 I tried;

```
button = tk.Button(frame,height = 0.5, width = 0.5)
```

& i also tried;

```
button = tk.Button(frame,height = (0,5), width = (0,5))
```

But they did not work...

Comment: not more ofcourse. I mean less than 1...

Comment: Protip: Tag your tkinter question with `tkinter`

Comment: Don't put corrections into comments. [edit] them into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pixel is the smallest unit of an image, it corresponds to a how bright a single light on a monitor is (3 lights for RGB).

You can not have half an element that takes up half a pixel, as a pixel is already the smallest unit of an image.

If you have a 4x4 grid of lights you can turn them on to make a 4x4 square, as well as a 3x3, 2x2 and 1x1 (single light on) but you cant make a 0.5x0.5 square.